# Remove the two biggest elements from array

Tags: java, arrays

I can fill my array,and found the two of biggest numbers.But,i can not delete it.May u guys could help me?

```
  int n = sc.nextInt();
  int [] myArray = new int[n];
  int first = 0;
  int second = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    int num = sc.nextInt();`
       if (num > first) {
         second = first;
         first = num;
    } else if(num > second) 
      {
      second = num;
      }
     }

   System.out.println("The largest  " + first+ "The second largest  " + second);
```

Comment: Why you can not remove it?

Comment: I assume that you expect your array to be shrunk by two elements? That isn't possible with arrays. You can set those elements to null. If you want to delete those elements use another data structure list `List`

Comment: Here is my Task: Write out to the console the mean average of a list of integers but ignore the two largest values.

Comment: If this is your task you don't have to delete anything from your array. While looping through the array to get the sum keep track of the 2 highest values. At the end subtract the sum of the two highest value of your sum and then divide by length-2 and you have it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 you can sort your array then you can loop throw your array and set it values to the other one avoiding the last two Integer for example :

```
//Your array
Integer[] array = {8, 99, 6, 336, 2};

//sort your array this can give your [2, 6, 8, 99, 336]
Arrays.sort(array);

//create a new array with the length = array - 2 if the length of array < 2 then 0
Integer[] array2 = new Integer[array.length > 2 ? array.length - 2 : 0];

//copy your array into the array2 avoiding the 2 last
System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, array.length > 2 ? array.length - 2 : 0);

//print your array, this will print [2, 6, 8]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
```

Comment: Ok, good one. However, stream is still an advanced approach for beginners. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Sort your arrays (default sort is ascending, i.e. from smallest to largest) then make a new copy of the array without the last two elements.

```
if(myArray.length > 2) {
    Arrays.sort(myArray);
    myArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length-2);
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need moar elements in array!");
}
```

Then perform any calculations on the resulting array. If you want to keep the original array, don't overwrite `myArray` when doing `copyOf()`.

Comment: this is true, but you should to check if the length is not less then 2 you will get `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` if your array is empty or contain 1 value

Comment: Error handling is left as an exercise to the reader. I just showed the shortest, most elegant way to handle this, instead of half-page loops that would confuse even the most hardened software archeologists.

Comment: Fine, I'll fix it for your sake.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a new array (in this case, `filteredArray`) in which you store all the elements in `myArray` but the greatest two.
Also, it is better to save the indexes of the two biggest numbers rather than their values in order to be able to filter them out more easily.

This should work (you will find the array you want in `filteredArray`).

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
int [] myArray = new int[n];
int first = 0;
int second = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    if (myArray[i] > myArray[first]) {
        second = first;
        first = i;
    } else if(myArray[i] > myArray[second]) {
        second = i;
    }
}
int [] filteredArray = new int[n-2];
int skipped = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(i != first && i != second)
        filteredArray[i - skipped] = myArray[i];
    else
        skipped++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply sort the array and find or remove the two biggest elements.

```
int [] myArray = new int[]{14,5,2,16,18,20};
System.out.println("The original array is "+ " " +Arrays.toString(myArray));
Arrays.sort(myArray);
System.out.println("The sorted array is "+ " " +Arrays.toString(myArray));;

int fisrtmax = myArray[myArray.length-1];
int secondmax = myArray[myArray.length-2];

System.out.println("The first biggest number is " + fisrtmax+ "  The second biggest number is " + secondmax);

int [] arrafterremove= Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length-2);


System.out.println("The array after removing the two biggest numbers is " + Arrays.toString(arrafterremove));
```

**RUN**

```
The original array is  [14, 5, 2, 16, 18, 20]
The sorted array is  [2, 5, 14, 16, 18, 20]
The first biggest number is 20  The second biggest number is 18
Array after removing the two biggest numbers is [2, 5, 14, 16]
```

Comment: what if the array contain just one value or it is empty `int[] myArray = new int[]{14};` you will get a error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you should to not avoid this point you can see my code bellow good luck

Comment: @ YCF_L, my solution was based on the original post. Any exception else, then the question should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

May be following code will useful for you

```
again :
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{            
     if ((a[i] < a[i+1]) && (i+1)<n)  
     {
         temp = a[i];
         a[i] = a[i+1];
         a[i+1] = temp;
         continue again;
     }           
}
System.out.println("The largest  " + a[0] + " & second largest " + a[i]);
```

IF you want to delete other then you can do that

```
for(int i=2; i<n ; i++)
   test = ArrayUtils.remove(a, i);
```